# Difference between Short, long and Long long int in C programming?

Tags: c

I am learning C programming online on my own so that I can be prepared for College in Winter 2016. I am learning about data types right now. 
I don't understand the difference between:

```
short
long
long long integers in C programming
```

I looked online, but I am still confused on how to use these and when.
Thank you.

Comment: Proposed duplicate does not consider `short` and the usual integer promotions that affect it and not `long`, `long long` as well as issues concerning `scanf()` and `short`, its use in fields, etc.  As C++ is a different language there are various subtle issues with these types in `C` and not relevant to `C++`.

Comment: Better use `<stdint.h>` & `int32_t` & `int64_t` & `intptr_t`

Comment: The duplicate is marked for C++ and this question is instead about C. Please reopen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C was originally written for 16-bit machines, where the fastest and most-convenient size of integer to work with were 16 bits.  This was the original `int` type.  Sometimes, programmers needed 32-bit numbers, so those were the `long int` type.

In due course, people ported C to 32-bit machines where the most convenient word size was 32 bits.  They wanted to keep using `int` to mean the native word size, because for example about every C program in the real world has `int i;` in it somewhere, but sometimes, they also needed to use 16-bit numbers to save space.  So those became the `short int` type.

Time passed, and C needed to be ported to 64-bit machines.  By then, there were a lot of programs in existence that assumed `long` was exactly 32 bits wide, and unfortunately, a lot of programs that also assumed that a `long` was the same size as a pointer, an IPv4 address, a file offset, a timestamp, etc.  Good code uses types such as `size_t`, `uintptr_t`, and `off_t` instead, but old versions of the system libraries defined their library functions to use `long`, so a lot of legacy code had to as well.  Since C99 came out, there have also been types such as `int32_t` in the standard library to specify exact widths, and Unix and Windows have had them under different names for a while.

As a consequence of the types being used to mean contradictory things, compilers today give programmers the choice between `long` being 32 and 64 bits wide, and 64-bit compilers let `int` be either 32 or 64 bits wide, too. At least one real compiler defined `int` as 64 bits (the native word length) but `long` as 32 bits (so the system libraries and code would still work).  The standards committee prohibited that in C11: `long long int` is now guaranteed to be at least as wide as `long int`, and `long int` at least as wide as `int`.

Because a lot of programs couldn't redefine `long` as 64 bits without breaking, C needed a new type that meant (at least) 64-bit.  By then, the standards committee was reluctant to introduce new keywords outside a header file, so they reused an existing one instead and named it `long long int`.

In brief, you shouldn’t make assumptions about what `int` and `long` mean beyond that `int` is at least 16 bits wide and fast, `long` is at least 32 bits wide, and on a C11 compiler `long` is at least as wide as `int` but no wider than `long long`.  For general purposes, use `int`.  If you need an array index, use `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t`.  If you want to be sure you can hold a number over 32,767, and seriously expect you might need to run on some 16-bit machine someday, use `long` or the fast type from `<inttypes.h>`.  If you’re making a system call, use the same type as its arguments.  If you’re storing a pointer in an integer type, use `uintptr_t`.  If you need a number at least 64 bits wide, use `long long`, and if you know exactly the width you need, use the exact-width type.

Comment: AFAIK `long long` is not 64 bits, but *at least* 64 bits. It might be 70 or 96 bits wide (even if I don't know any machine where it is the case)

Comment: On second thought, I just corrected my wording.  Thanks, Basile.

Answer (score 2):

They are just different data types. They have different ranges. All store integers, but consume different memory and have different ranges. For eg: `short int` consumes 16bits, `long int` consumes 32bits and `long long int` consumes 64bits. The maximum value of `short int` is 32767. So of you need to store big values you need to use `long int`. `Long long int` is the biggest and it can store upto 20!
More explanation and ranges are found here in the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/c_data_types) All the best!

Comment: This is not correct. Some of those types have *minimum* sizes, but not fixed ones.